# How to check if three specific letters exist in word using regular expression?

Tags: regex

For example I have a word: `telephone`. 
I need to check by regular expression existing of letters **t,l,p**.

> Not separately t or l or p, no ... all at once. If there is **t,l** but not **p** in the word then it means FALSE. The main aim to show that in this word all three letters in use.

I just need to get approvement of existence of theese three letters in one word from regular expression using **preg_match** in php

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147263/regular-expression-to-check-if-string-contains-specified-characters

Answer (score 0):

`\b(?=\S*t)(?=\S*l)(?=\S*p).+\b`
This regex will match any word containing all three letters `t`, `l` and `p`, regardless of the order.
Basically, you need to add (?=\S*x) for each letter you want the word to contain, where x is the letter you want.

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/km1xPV/2)

Comment: This would match `the` in `the-little-prince` for example - the `\S` in each lookahead should be `\W` instead (basically, it needs to be the exact complement of the `\w` that forms the actual match).

Comment: @jasonharper I can't see how replacing \S by \W could work... That's just not possible ^^ I intended to match things like `the-little-prince`. If you don't want to, and prefer to match words with only letters, replace \S by `[a-zA-Z]`, but definitely not `\W`. Edit : Actually, it didn't even match `the-little-prince` because of the `\w+`. It does now :)

Comment: oops, you're right, not `\W` - but I'd still do it as `\w` - `\S` can find the individual letters outside of the word that is returned by the match.

Comment: @jasonharper As I said, `\S` was on purpose, to match any word, even including special characters. By the way, using \w will still match `the_little_prince` or `dfvl45epsdf7t666` ;) And no \S can't find letters outside of the word, because it specifically anything **but** spaces.